# What happens to nonclustered indexes after partitioning

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-partitioning

I have a table with huge data volume (about 2TB) and want to improve performance by partitioning it monthly by CREATED_DATE column, as the application operates with data within one month.
The table has 3 non-clustered non-unique indexes, 2 of them include the CREATED_DATE column.

Thus I wonder what happens under the hood with these indexes after performing partitioning.

1. Do indexes get invalidated after partitioning?
2. Does partitioning operation include index rebuilding or I have to rebuild them by myself?
3. Can indexes which include Date column be rebuilt for a specific partition at a time but not for the whole table, as it could very long time?

Indexes are created as below:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table] ON [dbo].[Table](CREATED_DATE ASC, COL1 ASC, COL2 ASC, COL3 ASC) 
INCLUDE (COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL9, COL4, ...)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, FILLFACTOR =80) ON [PRIMARY];
 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_1] ON [dbo].[Table](COL4 ASC, COL3 ASC, CREATED_DATE ASC) 
INCLUDE (COL10, COL11)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, FILLFACTOR =80) ON [PRIMARY];
 
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table_2] ON [dbo].[Table](COL9 ASC, COL3 ASC, COL2 ASC, ...) 
INCLUDE (CREATED_DATE, COL5, COL6, COL7, COL8, COL4, COL10, COL11, ...)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, FILLFACTOR =80) ON [PRIMARY];
```

Thanks

Comment: please define "huge data volume". Aso, please post your table and index definitions

Comment: fill factor 80 won't help your 2TB size btw....

Comment: @MitchWheat, could you please help me to clarify other questions about partitioning?